# How to permanently switch "backspace" and "Enter" keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dconf, xkb

i want to swap the functions of Enter key and backspace .
i know the key code of both of them

"Enter"  = 117;
"Backspace"  = 101;

possible ways is by using the dconf editor by changing the options of xkb, but I don't know the name of the rules/options .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`xev` tells me that enter is keycode 36, so

```sh
# just to be sure, set any other key to Return! (here - (minus) mapped to Return
xmodmap -e 'keycode 61 = Return'
# not change keycode of Return to backspace 
xmodmap -e 'keycode 36 = BackSpace'
```

should work. Just make sure the command is called at login. Alternatively, you can modify the symbols file of your layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` if you are more inclined to to that.

**IMPORTANT**: make sure you have another way of sending the Return key, otherwise you won't be able to to much (even revert the keycode 36 back to Return without a Return key might prove impossible...). Above I mapped the "minus" key to Return.